# How to get component name which couses an error in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I created global handler for errors in my angular app:

```js
export class GlobalErrorHandlerComponent implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  handleError(error: Error) {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    console.log(error.name);
    console.log(router.url);
    console.log(error.message);
    const route = this.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    var snapshot = route.snapshot;
    console.log(snapshot.routeConfig.component.name); //unlucky it doesnt work :(
  }
}
```

I get all data which I needed for statistics, but I also want name of component which couses an error, I tried many things -one which have some sense - unlucky doesnt work.
Is any way to get that info?

edit: sample log
[image]

sample log v2 :)[image]

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of a sample printout from an error?

Comment: I added screenshot :)

Comment: is `error.stack` a property of your error variable? @Adam the component causing the error should be in the stacktrace, I worded my first question poorly, can you provide the output of `console.log(error)`

Comment: I added :) So the only way is parse stack trace? :(

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, yes. Does printing the first line of the stacktrace give the desired results?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, viewing the stacktrace through `error.stack` is the only way to view which component (and which line) is throwing the error.

Be wary though, it seems `error.stack` does not exist on all browsers, so you might want to use something like this to avoid any double errors:

```
try {
    console.log(error.stack);
} catch {
    console.log("Your browser does not support printing the stackTrace");
    // Nothing here, code contiues without throwing error.
}
```